# Backbone listener events not working

Tags: events, backbone.js, bind

I have two collections People and Teams.

I would like the Teams collection to listen if there has been a person added to the People collection.

However, I keep getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_listenerId' of undefined

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the concepts of bind and listenTo?  Below is the code I'm using for both collections.

```
        var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({

            url: '/people',

            model: Person,

            comparator: 'id',

            initialize: function() {

                //Why does this return '_listenerID of undefined'
                this.bind('add', function() {
                    var teams = new Teams;
                    teams.render;
                });

            },

        });


        var Teams = Backbone.Collection.extend({

            url: '/team',

            model: Team,

            comparator: 'id',

            initialize: function() {

                this.listenTo(People.collection, 'add', this.render);

            },

            render: function() {

                console.log("POOP")

            }

        });
```

Comment: `console.log("POOP")` I thought I was the only one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You indeed misunderstand how the listeners work. You're supposed to listen to some object (ie, an instance of a class) in particular.

Here Backbone tries to access the private property of a Backbone object `listenerId` to do some internal binding stuff. In your case, it's trying to get `People.collection._listenerId`. `People` is your class, and it doesn't have any `collection` property, so `People.collection` is undefined, thus your error.

Those are the basics of your problem. Having not entirely understood the links between your classes and what you're trying to do, I won't go any further at the moment.

Comment: Ahhhh okay.  Hrm, okay so I need to listen to an INSTANCE of a class... not just a class in general?

Comment: Also, I understand now that `People` doesn't have a `collection` property.  However, `people.collection` would work if I created `var people = new People`?

Comment: Got it to work now :)  I was getting confused as I saw other code where someone was calling `this.model` -- I figured I had to be just as specific when calling a collection, hence the use of `People.collection` -- But figuring out Backbone is a lot smarter than I am :p

Comment: @JIGGABITS if you saw something like `this.collection`, it can come from 2 things: a view representing a collection (you would then access the collection like that), or a model (you can access the collection the model is in like that). (Or something custom.) I guess you figured out the rest of the stated problems :p

Comment: same error in case when it gets a undefined variable as first parameter...